# Android No resource matches android:windowIsFloating

Tags: java, android, popup, themes, translucency

I am trying to make my activity as popup / floating activity after watching this video

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fn5OlqQuOCk

But I want to make window background Semi Translucent.
So I added windowIsFloating -> true

```
<style name="AppTheme.NamTheme">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">true</item>
</style>
```

But getting following error

> Error:(2374, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowIsFloating'.

Comment: Try adding a parent to your theme. `<style name="AppTheme.NamTheme" parent="android:Theme">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a parent android theme to your custom theme. For example,

```
<style name="AppTheme.NamTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution perfectly matched my needs.